# Olevba install linux issues

Tags: linux, malware-detection

I'm doing a lab on HTB and i need to download olevba, however when i do it doesn't work.  I'm using linux commands i'm using to install are, sudo apt install python3-pip then, in

I'm using linux commands i'm using to install are, sudo apt install python3-pip then, error message olevba is not a command

Answer (score 1):

This should allow you to create the command line:

```bash
sudo -H pip install -U oletools[full]
```

Refer to documentation : https://pypi.org/project/oletools/